# How to compile Angularjs nested directive with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a nested directive that has nested hierarchy.

```
angular.module("app", []);
angular.module("app").directive("hero", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<div>Hero {{number}}</div> <div ng-transclude></div>",
    scope: {
      number: "@"
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope) {

    }
  }
});
```

I can use it in html file like this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <hero number="1">
      <hero number="2">
        <hero number="3"></hero>
      </hero>
    </hero>
</div>
```

This works here [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/ekspkywp/1/).

---

Now I want to do this dynamically, and my hero model items are in a controller:

```
angular.module("app").controller("mainController", function ($scope) {
  $scope.heros = [
    { number: "1" },
    { number: "2" },
    { number: "3" },
  ]
});
```

And created a new `<hero-list>` directive that compiles all `<hero>` in controller model.

```
angular.module("app").directive("heroList", function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      data: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      var temp;
        angular.forEach(scope.data, function(item){
            var tempScope = scope.$new(true);
          tempScope.model = item;

          var item = angular.element('<hero model="model"></hero>');

          if(temp){
                if(temp.children().length){
                    var k = temp.children().append(item)
                  temp=k;
              }else
                temp.append(item);                   
          }else{
                temp = item;
          }
          $compile(item)(tempScope);

      });

      element.append(temp);
    }
  }
});
```

I will use it like this but does not compile nested, it appends and compiles under one other:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
     <hero-list data="heros"></hero-list>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Working ([demo-2](https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/ekspkywp/6/))

I think this is an advenced level problem.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with [ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) is a bit challenge here, however I can provide you an alternative here [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IUXANQMCcmnT2fRhKwHe?p=preview), if this is what you need!

To make `div` nested you need to manually find the child and append another element to it.
**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
  <hero-list data="heros">
    <div ng-class='number'>Hero {{number}}</div>
  </hero-list>
</div>
```

**Directive(js)**

```
angular.module("app").directive("heroList", function(){
        return {
      transclude: 'element',
      link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

      var heros = scope.$eval(attrs.data);
      heros.forEach(function(each,idx) {
        transclude(function(transEl, transScope) {
          transScope.number = each.number;
          if(idx===0)
          {
            el.parent().append(transEl);
          }
          else
          {
            el.parent().find("div").append(transEl);
          }
        });
      });
    }
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In your second example, you are passing an object instead of a number in your `hero` directive, so you need to use `model: "="` instead of `model: "@"`. Here is a working [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ekspkywp/4/).

Comment: But it appends elements under the other. I want to append as nested